# Nuxtjs loads pervious content

Tags: vue.js, caching, frontend, nuxtjs

Unfortunately, Nuxtjs loads previous content of posts and I must do a hard refresh on my browser to see the result I want!

For example: when I logged out I see my navbar changed, on the other hand, it completely logged out from the serverside, but after coming again to the website I see I am still logged in and I must do a hard refresh to see the result I want. It occurs to my whole project and the bad thing is, on my localhost everything is fine!

I would really appreciate it if you could help me.